# Excel VBA Drag and Drop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some difficulty finding a workable solution (been looking for 2 days now).
Hopefully you can help me figure it out.

**Purpose** - I'm trying to use VBA to drag and drop text between listboxes
(see image)

[image]

**Note**: I know there are Pivot Wizards already, I'm not so interested in them (long story)

**Question**
Is there any solution that you know of that could help me move "Column A" to any of the other listbox?

If you don't know of a solution, a blog or site might be helpful as well.

Comment: Pretty sure you can drag/drop on userforms... a button might be easier though.  Otherwise if you really want drag/drop, give me a minute to remember how I've done that before :)

Comment: Here is one link. http://exceldesignsolutions.com/drag-drop-items-between-listbox-controls/ It would be easier to add a button which will move the selected item from 1 listbox to the other. Let me know if you want an example.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I was not thinking anything that complicated... I literally did this last week just to see if it could be done. Can't find the file I was testing it with though... hold on :)

Comment: @DavidZemens: Definitely. Would love to see your code example :)

Comment: @SiddhartRout I did try the example you linked. However, the code inside was specifically geared for a 2 list scenario. I tried to modify it to a multiple listbox scenario but this became difficult

Comment: @SiddharthRout I can't for the life of me find it. I honestly think I didn't save the document because it seemed so easy -- now I'm kicking myself and not able to replicate. I'm pretty sure it was using the `BeforeDropOrPaste` and/or `BeforeDragOver` events.  But all the relevant examples that I'm finding now look more complicated than the simple one that I threw together...

Comment: @DavidZemens: No worries. This has happened with me a lot of time and hence I use [Handy Code Viewer](http://wikisend.com/download/230770/Untitled.png) to store all my code. ;)

Comment: well there is an old version I found here: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/A_5176-Handy-Code-Viewer.html

Comment: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2007/01/11/listbox-drag-and-drop/ does drag and drop in a single listbox, but it's just using Mouse events, so you may be able to do it between controls.

Comment: @DavidZemens: That was the first version when I was active in EE couple of years ago. I am not active there anymore. It's not updated. See this [LINK](http://www.siddharthrout.com/downloads/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to my comments above here is the most simple way to do it.

Create a Userform with 2 Listboxes and 1 Command Button as shown in the below image.

[image]

And paste this code in the Userform Code area

```
Dim i As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    For i = 1 To 10
        ListBox1.AddItem i
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select an item from listbox1"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ListBox2.AddItem ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)
    ListBox1.RemoveItem (ListBox1.ListIndex)
End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: I think this might work, let me give it a try (this might take an hour or two, I'm very slow)

Comment: It took me a while but I got my macro to use your help.

Comment: Does not answer original question regarding drag and drop

Comment: @RobertJ.: Yes it doesn't. Are you looking for a drag and drop? I can provide that answer. I just gave OP a simple way to achieve what OP actually wanted. BTW thanks for leaving a comment for the downvote. I really appreciate it :)